# Wifi repeater with bridge: connected but no internet on mobile phone but works fine on MacBook

Tags: wifi, access-point, pi-4

I live in a dorm where I don't have the physical access to the router. I want to set up a Pi as a Wi-Fi router with a bridge so that I could connect Philips Hue Bridge via Ethernet and then control the bulbs via mobile phone.

I am using RPi4B with Raspbian Buster and following [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge) excellent guide. I downgraded wpa_supplicant to v2.4 and hostapd to v2.6 since I'm using Buster instead of Stretch Lite.

After following the instructions I can connect to the access point, RPiNet, wirelessly and access the internet from my MacBook Pro just fine. However, from my mobile phone I can only connect to the access point but not get the internet.

I can ping my mobile phone from the laptop just fine. In fact, I can even control the hue bulbs since both the devices are on the same network. But neither my mobile phone nor Hue Bridge have the access to the internet.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Update:
Adding the DHCP server in the bridge network as suggested in the updated guide does the job. Thanks a lot!

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/16-br0_up.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=br0
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
EOF
```

Comment: If my answer and effort give you the solution to your problem it would be nice if you could accept the answer ;-) This will finish the question and show others that it has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge for Raspbian Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/revisions/89804/26) for your setup with Raspbian Buster. This doesn't work completely out of the box, so I have updated the tutorial.

Raspbian Stretch comes with **systemd 232** but Buster has **systemd 241** that fixes several bugs and changed things. *systemd 232* has default DNS server compiled in so if you don't define a DNS server you will get the default one. Look for a note into `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. In *systemd 232* you will find the line

```
#FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

in *systemd 241* this is set to `#FallbackDNS=` that means you do not have default DNS server anymore and always have to define DNS server given from the DHCP server (or you set `FallbackDNS=` but haven't tested it). So try the revised guide [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866) for your setup.